# MvxSpinner binding to ItemSource property not working

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxspinner

I have a very simple snippet as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.myco.app"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="20px">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/planATripLabel"
        android:textColor="#FF9900" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt" />

  <!--local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; " />-->

    <MvxSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The ViewModel contains the following code:

```
 private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "One", "Two", "Three"
        };
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); }
        }
```

However, when I run the application nothing is displayed.  The regular spinner does show its items as I have code in the view class itself copied from Xamarin's site like so:

```
  Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);

            spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
            var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                this, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `local` namespace is not taking into account `MvxBind`.

I'd replace

`xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.myco.app"`

with (I always use it like this, with res-auto)

`xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

And if that's not the problem I'd provide a custom `MvxItemTemplate` and a custom `MvxDropDownItemTemplate` to the `MvxSpinner` to see if the defaults are not working. And also check the `Output`window to see if any errors are being displayed.

If you need any help with that just tell me.

HIH

Comment: Turned out to be the namespace.  Made change as suggested and this cleared it up.  However, I am now getting these warnings:  The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto:MvxBind' attribute is not declared

Comment: As it states here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1413 you can ignore that warning

Comment: @KlausNji If it worked, please accept the answer, if not let me know to see if I can help